# Why vertical-align is not inherited in <a> from <li> element?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

To start i need to say that I am just starting with CSS & HTML.

Having following code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul {
  background-color: #2B3AA7;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.topnav ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topnav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo">
    <img alt="ISPF logo" src="logosmaller.png">
  </div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" id="indexnav">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="userdoc.html" id="userdocnav">Docs</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="download.html" id="downloadnav">Downloads</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content-body">content</div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see items in blue area are not completely vertically aligned. I found out i need to specify *vertical-alignment: middle;* in **a** elements so as in **li** elements. Why it is not inherited? Those **a** are inside **li**, so i would guess it should be inherited.

For example *font-family* from **body** is inherited everywhere.

Comment: "Why it is not inherited?" — Because the designers of the default stylesheet for your browser made that choice.

Comment: "For example font-family from body is inherited everywhere" — And *background-color* is not, so that doesn't mean much.

Comment: @Quentin So it is browser specific thing, not CSS? It might be inherited in different browser?

Comment: Browsers have more-or-less normalised their default stylesheets these days.

Answer (score -2):

`vertical-alignment: middle` only works inside `table` or children of divs with `display: table`.

What you could do here is match the `line-height` of the text inside `.topnav ul li a` with the height of the parent or set `display: flex` for the parent and then you can use `align-items: center` to center everything inside the parent vertically.